# Multi-isotope filtering with ramda

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope, ramda.js

I am enhancing an isotope application - and I am now in the process of trying to combine the values of a multi-filter to the application.

I've noticed 2 problems.

1st - is when I set a filter - it updates the state - but its almost like my state tree is one behind - it doesn't appear to have registered the setState directly after I look at the state. So the filtering isn't accurate.

2nd - the actual combination of multi-filters. So I know I could have 2 filters - and each may have a set of values

```
let availableFilters = ['statuspromo', 'regionspromo'];
//statuspromo
//regionspromo
let comboValues = [];
availableFilters.map(filter => {
    if(this.state['filteredOption_'+filter]){
        comboValues.push(this.state['filteredOption_'+filter]);
    }
});
```

this gives me a comboValues array -- that contains the 2 filters -- but now I need to combine them.

at this level comboValues - looks like [['LIVE', 'IN_PROGRESS'], ['SIEE']]

I first used ramda to flatten the array - flatten(comboValues) - but this will give me an OR situation.

I need to merge the two array sets or more ---- to be something like "opts = '.LIVE.SIEE, .IN_PROGRESS.SIEE'" - push this into the isotope filter arrange(opts) so that the 2 filters are in AND mode

what's the best way of doing this. Want to do this cleanly -- even the way I map over the combovalues with the old method I am adding a class variant and a join to get picked up on

```
let opts = comboValues.map(val => '.' + val).join(',');
let options = { filter: opts };
this.state.iso.arrange(options);
```

---

```
        let layer1 = [];
        let layer2 = [];

        let merged = [];

        if(comboValues[0]){
            layer1 = comboValues[0].map(val => '.' + val);//.join(',');
        }
        if(comboValues[1]){
            layer2 = comboValues[1].map(val => '.' + val);//.join(',');

            layer1.map(val1 => {
                layer2.map(val2 => {
                    merged.push(val1+''+val2);
                });
            });
        }

//let layer1 = [".EXPIRED", ".SONY_FINALIZING"]
//let layer2 = [".SIEJA-ASIA"]
//let merged = [".EXPIRED.SIEJA-ASIA", ".SONY_FINALIZING.SIEJA-ASIA"]

        console.log("layer1", layer1);
        console.log("layer2", layer2);

        console.log("merged", merged);

        let opts = merged.join(',');
        console.log("opts", opts);
        let options = { filter: opts };
        this.state.iso.arrange(options);
```

---

final current code

```
multiFilterIsotope = () => {
    console.log("this.state!!!!!!!!!!!", this.state);

    let availableFilters = ['statuspromo', 'regionspromo'];
    //statuspromo
    //regionspromo
    let comboValues = [];
    availableFilters.map(filter => {
        if(this.state['filteredOption_'+filter]){
            comboValues.push(this.state['filteredOption_'+filter]);
        }
    });

    //comboValues = flatten(comboValues);
    //console.log("comboValues", comboValues);

    let layer1 = [];
    let layer2 = [];

    let merged = [];

    if(comboValues[0] && comboValues[0].length > 0){
        layer1 = comboValues[0].map(val => '.' + val);//.join(',');

        //merged = layer1;
    }
    if(comboValues[1] && comboValues[1].length > 0){
        layer2 = comboValues[1].map(val => '.' + val);//.join(',');

        layer1.map(val1 => {
            layer2.map(val2 => {
                merged.push(val1+''+val2);
            });
        });
    } else {
        merged = layer1;
    }

    console.log("layer1", layer1);
    console.log("layer2", layer2);

    console.log("merged", merged);

    let opts = merged.join(',');
    console.log("opts", opts);
    let options = { filter: opts };
    this.state.iso.arrange(options);


    //comboValues = ["SONY_FINALIZING.SIEJA-ASIA", "EXPIRED.SIEJA-ASIA"];


    //let opts = comboValues.map(val => '.' + val).join(',');
    //let options = { filter: opts };
    //this.state.iso.arrange(options);
}
```

Comment: this looks like I need some kind of recursive function

Comment: This could really use some sample data, input and desired output.  It's really not clear to me what you're trying to do.  Now I don't know isotope, and that may be part of it.  But it sounds like the main problem is one of filtering and combining results, and that should be straightforward, but neither your text nor your code explains it well enough for me to get it.  Can you supply sample data?

Comment: `R.pipe (R.apply (R.xprod), R.map (R.join ('.')), R.map (R.concat ('.')))` is a function that would convert something like `[['LIVE', 'IN_PROGRESS'], ['SIEE']]` into something like `[".LIVE.SIEE", ".IN_PROGRESS.SIEE"]`.  But it's not at all clear to me if that's the sort of thing you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this -- but will this work with more filter options - like 3 filters?

```
    function mash(layer, m){
        let merge = [];

        console.log("layer", layer);

        m.map(val1 => {
            layer.map(val2 => {
                merge.push(val1 + '' + val2);
            });
        });
        if(m.length === 0){
            merge = layer;
        }
        return merge;
    }


    let merged = [];
    comboValues.map(layer => {
        let l = layer.map(val => '.' + val);
        //console.log('l', l);
        if(l.length > 0) {
            merged = mash(l, merged);
        }
    });
```